# twisted for python: Is there an ETA or beta for python v3?

Tags: python, twisted

We have launched a project in python v3. We will probably require twisted.

From what I see at present, this would require us to downgrade the project to python 2.7, which we would rather not do....

Is there a path to twisted in python v3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There is a plan.  [Please read it here.](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3)

The fact that there is a plan, however, does not mean that this will actually happen.  The core of Twisted is already ported to Python 3, so you can in a sense already use it, but to actually have *all* the code work on Python 3, the Twisted project needs volunteers with an active interest in porting things to Python 3, who will dedicate time and energy to executing that plan.  If you're planning to deploy Twisted on Python 3, then we really need you to pick up a couple of the tickets mentioned on that plan and contribute fixes for them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a plan for Python 3 support, and certain parts of the framework already work in Python 3.

See [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3) for more information on the roadmap, current status, and specific trac ticket numbers.